# Symfony - Form Inheritance - How to override or add a new attribute?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm using a Form Inheritance and I whould like to add or replace a class on my 'title' (already existing in my BookType) . how can I do that please ?

```
class ValidationBookType extends BookType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder

                ????????????????????????????????????????
                ->add('title', 'text', array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'newclass'
                    )
                ))
                ????????????????????????????????????????
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Video2Learn\BddBundle\Entity\Book',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'step',
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'Book';
    }

}
```

with a `->setAttribute(` ?

thanks !

**EDIT** **found a solution**

I found a solution but may be there is a better way ... ??

I did that :

```
class ValidationBookType extends BookType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $parent = parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $array = $parent->get('title')->getOptions();
        $array['read_only'] = true;

        $builder
                ->remove('title')
                ->add('title', 'text', $array)


        ;
    }
```

How can I improve that ? is there a  way more conventional ?

Comment: Might not be the nicest way but you do a `$form->remove('title')->add('title', ... etc)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem with this :

```
class ValidationBookType extends BookType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $parent = parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $array = $parent->get('title')->getOptions();
        $array['read_only'] = true;

        $builder
                ->remove('title')
                ->add('title', 'text', $array)


        ;
    }
```